# Jquery validation custom message for different elements changing dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form with dimension fields and I validate the form as follows.

```
$("#myForm").validate({
        rules:{
            "length" : {
                required: true,
                number: true,
                range: [0, 101.1]
            },
            "width" : {
                required: true,
                number: true,
                range: [0, 101.1]
            },
            "weight" : {
                required: true,
                number: true,
                range: [0, 99.999]
            }
        },
        messages : {
            "length" : {
                required: globalCtx.requiredMsg,
                range: $("#selectedUnit").val() =="true" ? globalCtx.invalidSizeMetric : globalCtx.invalidSizeImperial
            },
            "width" : {
                required: globalCtx.requiredMsg,
                range: $("#selectedUnit").val() =="true" ? globalCtx.invalidSizeMetric : globalCtx.invalidSizeImperial 
            },
            "weight" : {
                required: globalCtx.requiredMsg,
                range: $("#selectedUnit").val() =="true" ? globalCtx.invalidWeightMetric : globalCtx.invalidWeightImperial
            }
        }
    });
```

Every time the units is changed i call the function below to change the error message to reflect imperial messages.

```
function changeMetric(){
if($("#selectedUnit").val() =="true"){
        jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, {
            "weight":{
                range: globalCtx.invalidWeightMetric
            },
            "length" : {
                    range: globalCtx.invalidSizeMetric
                },
            "width" : {
                    range: globalCtx.invalidSizeMetric
                }
        });
    }else{
        jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, {
            "weight":{
                range: globalCtx.invalidWeightImperial
            },
            "length" : {
                range: globalCtx.invalidSizeImperial
            },
            "width" : {
                range: globalCtx.invalidSizeImperial
            }
        });
    }
}
```

But this function is not updating the error message.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to `return` the variables from within a function or they will not be evaluated dynamically...

```
messages: {
    length: {
        required: function(element) {
            return globalCtx.requiredMsg;
        },
        range: function(element) {
            return $("#selectedUnit").val() =="true" ? globalCtx.invalidSizeMetric : globalCtx.invalidSizeImperial;
        }
    }, ....
```