# How change JQuery Validation Message without refreshing website

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jQuery Validation from here: https://jqueryvalidation.org. Currently, I have two types of Messages prepared. They are popping out. When I'm changing language on web variables global variable with messages also is changing, but message in validator don't. Language of the validator change after I refresh the website. How can I change it on live without refreshing the website?

HTML is no needed, because everything is happening in JS file.
This is a function that are changing values in the object.
JS:

```
function setLang(lang) {
    (lang) ? lang: "pol";

    if (lang == "pol") {
        Messages = {
            formFirstnameRequired: 'Pole imie jest wymagane!',
            formLastnameRequired: 'Pole nazwisko jest wymangane!',
            formEmailRequired: 'Pole email jest wymagane!',
            formTitleRequired: 'Pole Tytuł jest wymagane!',
            formMessageRequired: 'Pole wiadomość jest wymagane!',
        }
    } else if (lang == "eng") {
        Messages = {
            formFirstnameRequired: 'Field firstname is required!',
            formLastnameRequired: 'Field lastname is required!',
            formEmailRequired: 'Field email is required!',
            formTitleRequired: 'Field title is required!',
            formMessageRequired: 'Field message is required!',
        }
    }
}
```

I'm also using this cookie for managing the language of this form validation:

```
if (getCookie("lang") == null) {
        document.cookie = 'lang=pol';
    }

    setLang(getCookie("lang"));

    $(".nav").on("click", "#polLang", (event) => {
        document.cookie = 'lang=pol';
        setLang(getCookie("lang"));
    });

    $(".nav").on("click", "#engLang", (event) => {
        document.cookie = 'lang=eng';
        setLang(getCookie("lang"));
    });
```

Here I have validation
JS:

```
 $("#contactForm").validate({
        rules: {
            "formFirstname": {
                required: true,
            },
            "formLastname": {
                required: true,
            },
            "formEmail": {
                required: true,
            },
            "formTitle": {
                required: true,
            },
            "formMessage": {
                required: true,
            }
        },
        messages: {
            "formFirstname": {
                required: Messages.formFirstnameRequired,
                string: true
            },
            "formLastname": {
                required: Messages.formLastnameRequired,
                string: true
            },
            "formEmail": {
                required: Messages.formEmailRequired,
                email: true,
            },
            "formTitle": {
                required: Messages.formTitleRequired,
                string: true
            },
            "formMessage": {
                required: Messages.formMessageRequired,
                string: true
            }
        },
        onfocusout: false,
        errorPlacement: function(error) {
            toastr.error(error);
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            toastr.success('success')
            return false;
        },
        invalidHandler: function() {
            return;
        }
    });
```

Comment: *I'm also using this cookie for managing the language of this form validation:* <-- This may be the source of the issue. When is this cookie read?

Comment: Everything with cookies are in front of the JS, so they are first to run. Language is set, then I change it by button to different one and when I'm trying validation the form is still the same and after refreshing the website I have a new language.

Comment: Please use the search function:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/38796449/594235

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery validator msgs are static. If you want to update them dynamically you can create a function, that will return a new msg.
Like this:

```
"formFirstname": {
            required: function getFormFirstname() { return Messages.formFirstnameRequired },
            string: true
        },
```